# GET parameters from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

newbie here.
I've made a simple form in the index.html as you can see below:

```
<form name="parameters" METHOD="GET" ACTION="pag1.html">
login: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="login"> 
password: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="password"> 
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

On pag1.html i've placed my javascript to split the URL, as you can see below:

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function processUser()
  {
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
l = unescape(temp[1]);
temp = parameters[1].split("=");
p = unescape(temp[1]);
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l;
document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = p;
  }
</script>
</head>
```

And two DIVs to display both of them:

```
<div id="log">LOGIN:</div>
<div id="pass">PASSWORD:</div>
```

The URL on pag1.html is like: " pag1.html?login=123&password=asd "

But all that i get is :
LOGIN:

PASSWORD:

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: use `<input type="password">` for passwords, and never send forms via GET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: There is a chance that the JS is running before the divs are rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be called after whole HTML is loaded. To do that you need to place your function as a callback of DOMContentLoaded event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    function processUser()
    {
         var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

         var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
         l = unescape(temp[1]);
         temp = parameters[1].split("=");
         p = unescape(temp[1]);
         document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l;
         document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = p;
    }

    processUser();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just because your code is executed before #log and #pass rendering in the DOM. Just put your  before the  closing tag and it will works.

Comment: Still didn't get it. Could you please be more accurate?

Comment: Try to move your script from the <head> element to the end of your <body> element.

Comment: don't forget to call your function processUser(); at the end of your script